# CSV to Excel Doc?

Tags: excel, csv, interop

**I was curious what the community thinks is the easiest way to take a CSV file and 'save as' a Excel document with only a couple formulas pasted in?**

I am trying to do this behind the scenes, and not physically navigating. e.g. opening, selecting save As, etc -- **even though this is already VERY simple I **need to do this in code (Think automation)**

Background: I have a c++ command line program generating the .csv, and a C# GUI starting this process. Either programs could hold the code, but I figure this is easiest in C# (InterOp?) The reasons I don't directly send code into the csv is because of the amount of comma characters that will mess up the csv and because other Excel documents need to reference the sheets so they need to be in .xls format.

```
=AVERAGE(C2:C999)
=COUNTIFS(C:C,">0",C:C,"<31")
=COUNTIFS(C:C,">31",C:C,"<55")
=COUNTIF(C:C,">55")
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look and see whether command-line scipting of openoffice will do the job. It can do quite a lot of conversions very easily. Otherwise there are a lot of Excel-producing libraries, for example PHPExcel, but you'd need to wrap some programming around them.